# ¿Qué es un "pichiruchi"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, adjetivos

Hoy os voy a dejar que sea Manolito quien haga la pregunta:

[image: Manolito es un pichiruchi]

Pues eso: ¿qué quiere decir *pichiruchi*? Lo más cercano que existe en el DRAE es:

> **[pichirruchi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sv8Mlxf)**
>
> 1. m. coloq. Perú. Persona insignificante.

También he visto que significa "persona de poco valor". Sin embargo, me gustaría que algún autóctono explicara el uso de la palabra con algo más de detalle: ejemplos de uso, si es conocida o es poco usada, si es cierto que se la inventó Quino para la tira o si venía de antes, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cualquier chileno sabe lo que significa *pichiruchi*. Es algo sin valor o sin importancia. Viene del mapuzungún, la lengua de la etnia mapuche, a partir de la palabra *pichiruche* ('e' final) y con el significado original de "flacucho". [Aquí se detalla la etimología](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?pichiruche).

Answer (score 4):

Toda la vida pensé, aunque sin fundamento, que Quino la había inventado, pero encuentro diversas fuentes anteriores a la publicación de la tira que hacen derivar la palabra del [mapuche](https://books.google.com/books?id=CKFDAQAAMAAJ&q=pichiruchi&dq=pichiruchi&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y) o del [guaraní](https://books.google.com/books?id=AmVlAAAAMAAJ&q=pichiruchi&dq=pichiruchi&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y). Puede que Quino la haya utilizado después de habérsela escuchado a alguien del Perú o de Chile, pues la gracia es que no es una palabra que se use en Argentina y por eso Manolito la desconoce. En [la siguiente tira](http://65.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ljoehft6ct1qe3rjgo1_500h.jpg), Manolito confunde la palabra y dice "Machu Picchu" (me parecería excesivo suponer que sea un guiño a un posible origen peruano del término, pero todo puede ser) y, en [la que le sigue](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BHgZTTHCcAA_4bS.jpg), Mafalda dice sobre su significado: "No sé explicártelo; Pichiruchi puede usarse para definir muchas cosas".

Comment: Ciertamente, en las siguientes tiras se insiste en la expresión, pero no se llega a ninguna conclusión, por eso he preguntado.

Comment: En las tiras de Mafalda, Manolito es hijo *gallegos* (españoles, vamos), así que no habla exactamente igual que otros personajes. Así que puede desconocer la palabra porque en su casa no se usa. Claro que en otra tira posterior Felipe tampoco la conoce, así que no sé bien dónde queda mi razonamiento.

Answer (score 1):

Persona de muy escasa experiencia o solvencia profesional, insignificante intrascendente.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta, citando alguna referencia que apoye tus afirmaciones, y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No dudes en pedir ayuda si lo necesitas. Bienvenido de nuevo. ¡Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Answer (score 1):

Pichiruchi, se usa en el Peru para denotar que algo es insignificante, de poco valor. Se puede utilizar refiriéndose a una persona: " ese hombre es un pichiruchi, no esta a tu altura" o tambien se puede utilizar para hablar de una cosa sin valor: "ese regalo que me trajiste es un adefesio, regalo pichiruchi"; hoy en dia ya no es tan utilizada la palabra por las nuevas generaciones, se oye mas en personas de la generacion de los 80 para abajo....

Answer (score 0):

aqui me apreciacion de la palabra Pichiruchi..... Para empezar no se la fecha de que se utiliza esta palabra, pero entiendo que ..."Pichiruchi" es una palabra que suele darse al muchacho o joven mozolbete, pero en forma ciertamente despectiva, insignificante, de poca experiencia en cierta forma, pero la conozco mas de 70 años, aqui en Breña, Lima, Perú.

Answer (score -2):

La variante en Peru es pichirruchi, en mapudungun dialecto mapuche es : pichi= pequeño , poco, ej: ciudad de  Pichilemu= pequeño bosque.

Comment: OK, en "Perú es pichirruchi", pero no explicas el significado de Pichiruchi, que es lo que se pregunta. Otras respuestas ya aportan que etimológicamente proviene del mapuzungún